# php loop repetitive execution

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

what can i change in this code to make the output from [This](https://snag.gy/Be0xzU.jpg) to make it look like [This](https://snag.gy/vmnrya.jpg)

**The two 'This' links are screenshots of the layouts**
I want all the boxes to be in-line / next to each other just like the second screenshot.

i programmed the layout in html and it worked when trying php the layout just messed up.

```
function getTest(){

  global $con;

  $get_pro = "select * from drinks";

    $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro); 

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){

    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
      $cat = $row['cat'];
      $image = $row['image'];
      $desc = $row['desc'];
      $qty = $row['qty'];
      $price =$row['price'];
      $status= $row['status'];


echo "<!--==========================\n"; 
echo "  Price Menu\n"; 
echo "============================-->\n"; 
echo "      <!-- Page Content -->\n"; 
echo "      <main class=\"entry-content\">\n"; 
echo "          <section class=\"page-section\">\n"; 
echo "              <div class=\"container\">\n"; 
echo "              \n"; 
echo "                  <div class=\"row\">\n"; 
echo "                      <div class=\"col-md-12\">\n"; 
echo "                          <div class=\"isotope-filters\" role=\"group\">\n"; 
echo "                              <div class=\"btn-group\">\n"; 

// the categories go here

echo "                              </div>\n"; 
echo "                          </div>\n"; 
echo "                      </div>\n"; 
echo "                  </div>\n"; 
echo "                  <br><br>\n"; 
echo "                  <div class=\"row isotope-wrapper isotope-beers-wrapper\">\n"; 
echo "                      <div class=\"isotope isotope-beers gutter\">\n"; 
echo "                          <div class=\"grid-item col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-ms-6 col-xs-12 $cat\">\n"; 
echo "                              <div class=\"grid-wrapper\">\n"; 
echo "                                  <a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" data-remodal-target=\"bottle-$id\">\n"; 
echo "                                      <figure style=\"background-image: url('admin/images/drinks/$image')\">\n"; 
if ($row['status'] === 'Yes'){
echo "                                      <div class=\"offer\"></div>\n"; 
}
echo "                                          <figcaption class=\"grid-content\">\n"; 
echo "                                              <h5 class=\"grid-title\"><span>$title</span></h5>\n"; 
echo "                                          </figcaption>\n"; 
echo "                                      </figure>\n"; 
echo "                                  </a>\n"; 
echo "                              </div>\n"; 
echo "                          </div>\n"; 
echo "                      </div>\n"; 
echo "                  </div>\n"; 
echo "\n"; 
echo "              </div>\n"; 
echo "          </section>\n"; 
echo "      </main><!-- /.enry-content -->\n"; 
echo "\n"; 
echo "      <!-- Off-Page Content -->\n"; 
echo "      <!-- Mobile Navigation (Left Panel) -->\n"; 
echo "      <!-- Preloader -->\n"; 
echo "      <div class=\"introLoading\"></div>\n"; 
echo "      <!-- Back to Top -->\n"; 
echo "      <div>\n"; 
echo "          <a class=\"back-to-top fa fa-chevron-up\" href=\"javacript:void(0);\"></a>\n"; 
echo "      </div>\n"; 
echo "      <!-- Modal Content -->\n"; 
echo "      <div class=\"remodal-bg\">\n"; 
echo "          <!-- Item One -->\n"; 
echo "          <div class=\"remodal modal-beers\" data-remodal-id=\"bottle-$id\">\n"; 
echo "              <button data-remodal-action=\"close\" class=\"remodal-close\"></button>\n"; 
echo "              <div class=\"row\">\n"; 
echo "                  <div class=\"col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12\">\n"; 
echo "                      <div class=\"item-modal-image\">\n"; 
echo "                          <a class=\"image-lightbox\" href=\"admin/images/drinks/$image\"><img alt=\"\" src=\"admin/images/drinks/$image\" /></a>\n"; 
echo "                      </div>\n"; 
echo "                  </div>\n"; 
echo "                  <div class=\"col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12\">\n"; 
echo "                      <h3>$title</h3>\n"; 
echo "                      <p>$desc</p>\n"; 
echo "                      <table class=\"table\">\n"; 
echo "                          <tbody>\n"; 
echo "                              <tr>\n"; 
echo "                                  <td>Price:</td>\n"; 
echo "                                  <td>£$price</td>\n"; 
echo "                              </tr>\n"; 
echo "                              <tr>\n"; 
echo "                                  <td>Quantity:</td>\n"; 
echo "                                  <td>$qty</td>\n"; 
echo "                              </tr>\n"; 
echo "                          </tbody>\n"; 
echo "                      </table>\n"; 
echo "                  </div>\n"; 
echo "              </div>\n"; 
echo "          </div>\n"; 
echo "      </div>  \n"; 
echo "\n"; 
echo "    <!--==========================\n"; 
echo "  Price Menu end\n"; 
echo "============================-->\n";

}

}
```

Comment: @WheatBeak i made the layout in html then just converted it to php using a HTML->PHP converter

Comment: My first guess would be that your problem is you are putting `<div class="container"` ,`<div class="row">`, etc. etc., in each iteration of the loop

Comment: you should stuff PHP between HTML, you did reverse by using `echo`

Comment: It looks like you are inserting that entire block of `echo`s on each loop pass. Which would give you the results shown in the first screenshot. My suggestion would be to research more about how to utilize html in a php page because this is not how you should be doing it.

Comment: i figured it out guys thanks  it was that i was ittarating the whole code twice

Answer (score 0):

Take all of your html out of the `echos` and instead insert PHP into your html.  First you need to identify the areas of your html which need to loop, for example if my original html was this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        Box 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        Box 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        Box 3
    </div>
</div>
```

But I wanted to generate the 3 boxes dynamically instead, my PHP would be something like this, which you can wrap in a function:

```
<?php
function outputStuff(){

    $contents = array("Box 1","Box 2","Box3");
?>

    <div class="row">

    <?php foreach($contents as $value):?>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">

            <?php echo $value; ?>

        </div>

    <?php endforeach;?>

    </div>

<?php 
} // end the function 
?>
```

The `row` has to be outside the loop otherwise it will be created for each item and clear the floats on the columns.  Use these basic principles and you will achieve what you want.

Comment: Bro I want to use a separate functions page otherwise the page would look messy

Comment: You can still wrap this kind of code in a function, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using bootstrap, I suggest you to use this kind of structure

[Take a look on this page](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/9WZX)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 picture">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="//placehold.it/200x200">   
        </span>

        <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="//placehold.it/200x200">   
        </span>

        <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="//placehold.it/200x200">   
        </span>

        <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="//placehold.it/200x200">   
        </span>
    </div></div>
```